# Executing EntityFramework Core LINQ query with generic types

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I am trying to implement some base class for a service that fetches objects from the database using EF Core and generics.
Consider the following class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Base entity getter service
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TEntity">The  database entity type</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TPK">The primary key type for example: int</typeparam>
class Service<TEntity, TPK>{
    protected Func<TEntity, TPK, bool> pkFinder;
    
    public Service(string pkname) {
        var entityExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "instance");
        var propertyExpr = Expression.Property(entityExpr, pkname);
        var pkExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TPK), "value");
        var eqExpr = Expression.Equal(propertyExpr, pkExpr);
        pkFinder = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, TPK, bool>>(eqExpr, entityExpr, pkExpr).Compile();
    }
    public TEntity Get(TPK pk){
       return ctx.Set<TEntity>().Where(e=>pkFinder.Invoke(e, pk)).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

The *pkname* parameter is the name of the property that holds the primary key for that entity (typically "Id")

The *ctx* object is the EF context.

The above code ( or something very similar as this example is oversimplified for clarity) fails with Entity Framework unable to translate the expression.

The only thing that has worked so far is implementing an override in each derived class for the .Where clause with actual non generic types, however I would like to avoid reimplementing the same code over and over.

Another idea was to make the entity classes to derive from some base class but since they are autogenerated, that could be problematic.

Any new ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've already got all the code for generating an expression to check the ID against a known value. Just put that into your `Get` method and use an `Expression.Constant` with the `pk` value rather than an `Expression.Parameter` for your `pkExpr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already got all the code for generating an expression to check the ID against a known value. Just put that into your `Get` method and use an `Expression.Constant` with the `pk` value rather than an `Expression.Parameter` for your `pkExpr`.

I haven't tested it, but something like this should work:

```
private readonly string pkname;
public Service(string pkname) {
    this.pkname = pkname;
}
public TEntity Get(TPK pk){
    var entityExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "instance");
    var propertyExpr = Expression.Property(entityExpr, pkname);
    var pkExpr = Expression.Constant(pk, typeof(TPK));
    var eqExpr = Expression.Equal(propertyExpr, pkExpr);
    var pkFinder = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(eqExpr, entityExpr);
    return ctx.Set<TEntity>().Where(pkFinder).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't that mean I will have to re-compile the expression on each execution? Or rather EF will recompile it each time?

Comment: Yep, it worked and the performance hit is insignificant. Thanks a lot. One of this things like "How haven't I thought of it before...". Must be the late hour. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, to answer your earlier question, the expression doesn't need to be "compiled" at all. It only needs to get _built_, and then _interpreted_ by Entity Framework, all of which is what happens if you have a hard-coded expression anyway. If you look at the IL code generated when you say `e => e.Id == id` in code, it's actually generating calls to all those `Expression` methods.